# YouTube video in Android

Tags: android, youtube

I am trying to load a YouTube video in Android.

I have added a WebView in xml:

```
  <WebView android:id="@+id/VideoView"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

I then load it as follows:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);

String htmlString = "<html> <body> <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XS998HaGk9M\"; type=application/x-shockwave-flash width="+640+" height="+385+"> </embed> </body> </html>";   
webview.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I have added the proper permissions to the manifest. All I receive is a blank white screen and nothing loads.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `webview`, just start a new `Intent`...

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
       Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XS998HaGk9M")));
```

Comment: +1 As this will also allow older phones which don't support flash to ue the YouTube client.

Comment: I have tried to use that but I get a webpage not available. Also I want to try and control how much of the view will show a youtube video which is why I went with webview.

Comment: if the webpage is not available then that is your problem ;-)

Comment: Yes I know, it says on received error in log cat url not found. Any ideas?

Comment: That means your url is not valid or the video you trying to access is wrong, try another video

Comment: +1 for Ryan Berger.Just the way I wanted,a single line of code!